# ¿Cómo crear nueva variable (columna) en un data frame usando el bucle for?

Tags: r, dataframe

Tengo un dataframe llamado `base`. El cual tiene las siguientes columnas (como se muestra en la imagen).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que deseo es convertir a mayúsculas, para lo cual uso el comando `toupper()` de la siguiente manera.

```
base$P65_1<-toupper(base$P65_1)
```

Mi pregunta es, cómo hago que las 6 columnas se conviertan a mayúscula usando el bucle for. Soy nuevo y en mi inocencia realicé lo siguiente:

```
for (i in 1:6) {
        base$P65_[i]<-toupper(base$P65_[i])
}
```

Ese código no sirve, definitivamente. Por favor, cómo lo soluciono usando bucles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando un bucle `for` tal como intentaste, es posible, pero debes acceder a cada columna por índice (o posición), o bien construir dinámicamente el nombre:

#### Opción 1 por índice

```
for (i in 1:6) {
    base[,i] <- toupper(base[,i])
}
```

#### Opción 2 por nombres

```
for (i in 1:6) {
    base[,paste0("P65_",i)] <- toupper(base[,paste0("P65_",i)])
}
```

De cualquier forma, con R base una forma mucho más sencilla es usar un bucle implícito:

```
columnas <- grep("P65", colnames(base))
base[, columnas] <- apply(base[, columnas], 2, toupper)
```

Detalle:

- Con `grep("P65", colnames(base))` obtenemos los índices de las columnas que coincidan con el patrón `P65`
- Con `apply(base[, columnas], 2, toupper)` "aplicamos" la función `toupper` por cada columna (`MARGIN = 2`)

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. Me sirvió definitivamente.